# Double string into variable

Tags: php, string, variables

Basic question, I'm sure this has been answered before. But since I'm not familiar with PHP I don't know what to search for, hence the title of this question.

This code outputs  *'my custom field value'*

```
$title = stripslashes($_POST['user-submitted-customfield']);
```

I'd like to make it *'my custom value from @mysite'*, something like

```
$title = stripslashes($_POST['user-submitted-customfield']) + from + @mysite;
```

which I tried and returned an error

Comment: In PHP, you use `.` for concatenating variables, so write `$title = stripslashes($_POST['user-submitted-customfield']) . 'from' . '@mysite';` instead.

Comment: Thanks :) had no idea what conacteting mean

Comment: It always helps to google a bit first. Searching for `join variables php` or `join strings php` would have given you the right results. Cheers!

Comment: I did Google, I searched for double variable, two values in one variable, two strings in variable etc. I do see now that the key term was 'join' which was not easy for me to have guessed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

concat string in PHP

USING `.`

```
stripslashes($_POST['user-submitted-customfield']).' from @mysite';
```

from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

> There are two string operators. The first is the concatenation
>   operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left
>   arguments. The second is the concatenating assignment operator ('.='),
>   which appends the argument on the right side to the argument on the
>   left side. Please read Assignment Operators for more information.

Answer (score 2):

```
$title = stripslashes($_POST['user-submitted-customfield']).'from'.'@mysite';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a complete string you have to concat the strings with `.` and you have to set your words in quotes.

```
$title = stripslashes($_POST['user-submitted-customfield']).' from @mysite';
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP is different from javascript, we use dots to concatinate strings and strings must be quoted:

```
$title = stripslashes($_POST['user-submitted-customfield']) . "from @mysite";
```

Comment: Ah, why can't they make the languages similar

Comment: Why would they make them similar?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve that result. Some of them are:

```
$user_feedback = stripslashes($_POST['user-submitted-customfield']);

$title = $user_feedback . ' from @mysite';
echo $title;
echo '<br>';

$title = "$user_feedback from @mysite";
echo $title;
echo '<br>';

$title = "{$user_feedback} from @mysite";
echo $title;
echo '<br>';

$template = ':user_feedback from @mysite';
$title = str_replace(':user_feedback', $user_feedback, $template);
echo $title;
echo '<br>';

$template = '%s from @mysite';
$title = sprintf($template, $user_feedback);
echo $title;
echo '<br>';
```